# How can I configure a Azure DevOps Release Pipeline to package PowerShell scripts?

Tags: azure-devops

I'm new to Azure DevOps and I'm trying to understand how to package a release of a PowerShell script project I'm working on.

I'm previously familiar with GitHub and the manual process for drafting a new release of my project repo.  I'm now experimenting with Azure DevOps and what I want to achieve is a similar output to GitHub where my repo of PowerShell scripts are packaged into a zip file which I can publish for release.

I'm not familiar with the pipeline process in Azure DevOps or YAML as a newbie to proper release cycle tools.  Previously I've just created scripts and shared them simply as they are or dropped them into a GitHub repo and manually packaged a release.  I'm not likely to be turning out large numbers of builds and so have never had to come at this from an automated standpoint which seems to be the way Azure is driving me unless I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty simple.  I prefer to do this using the old-fashing GUI (hint: there is a link when starting a new Build Pipeline that says `Use the classic editor`), and then convert to YAML **after** I get my Build Pipeline working.

1) Create your standard Build Pipeline.
2) Add the step to ZIP your files
[image]

3) Add properties to that Archive step.  Specify the source to zip and target where you want the zip file to end up at.
[image]

4) Lastly, convert that single step to a YAML step by clicking in the upper-right corner on the link `View YAML`.
[image]

There are a lot of steps I am leaving out, but I hope this leads you into the right direction.

Comment: Thank you!  Heading in the right direction.  Still working to get it worked out but I think I'm on the right path.  Am I missing anything or is it really poorly documented at this point?

Comment: What I'm leaving out is how to start creating a Build Pipeline.  But here you have the individual YAML step to create a zip file.  The documentation for all of the core steps are documented, but you can find the `Archive Files` task here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/archive-files

Comment: Thank you again for the guidance!